# i declared label in java but still it shows 'the label is missing'

Tags: java

my code is

---

```
repeat : // label name

  System.out.println("For Continue Press '1' or For Exit Press '0' ");

  int cont=read.nextInt();

  if(cont!=1 || cont!=0)

  {

    continue repeat;
  }
```

---

i installed jdk 9 in my system, please suggest me something

Comment: how would you "continue" a print statement? You can only continue loops unless i'm mistaken. Are you trying to use a version of GOTO here?

Comment: are you working with netbeans swing? please post more code

Comment: Also please note that `cont!=1 || cont!=0` will allways be true because `cont` cannot be 1 and 0 at the same time (so it will allways be not equal to one of those two values)

Comment: Even `continue` shouldn't work if the code isn't embedded in a loop ...

Comment: Awful code.  No one should write like this in this day and age.

Comment: Please look into java basics, what you created might be how it works in shell scripts and BASIC, but not in modern programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

The label should appear directly before a loop control statement, i.e., `for`, `do` or `while`.

`continue` is not a replacement for "goto".

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html for more information

Answer (score 2):

Use a `do` loop here instead of your current approach:

```
System.out.println("For Continue Press '1' or For Exit Press '0' ");
int cont;

do {
    cont = read.nextInt();
} while (cont != 1 && cont != 0);

// the rest of your code (cont now must equal zero or one)
```